# How can I get all categories belonging to multiple collections

Tags: laravel

So I am trying to get all the category id's from multiple model instances combined into one array.

**Activities model:**

```
class activities extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(category::class);
    }
}
```

I want to get all the category id's from the following query:

```
$activities = activities::where('notified', false)->get();
```

I have tried it like this but it isn't working

```
$categories = activities::where('notified', false)->categories()->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `with()` query function.

```
$categories = activities::where('notified', false)->with('categories')->get()->pluck('categories.id');
```

I also recommend your Model names are capitalised. This is standard in Laravel and considered best practice more generally.

Comment: I get this error:
`
"class": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `categories`.`id` from `activities` where `notified` = 0 and `activities`.`deleted_at` is null)",
`

Comment: Fixed my answer. You'll need to put a `get()` between your `with()` and `pluck()`.

Comment: Thanks! I cant try it right now, but I will when I'm back home.

Comment: If I do this I get: `[null,null]`, And if I do `pluck('categories')` instead of `pluck('categories.id'),` I get:
`[[{"id":4,"name":"Test","pivot":{"activities_id":1,"category_id":4}}],[{"id":4,"name":"Test","pivot":{"activities_id":2,"category_id":4}},{"id":5,"name":"Everyone","pivot":{"activities_id":2,"category_id":5}}]]`